# Can bigger persons generally resist g-forces better?

Tags: human-biology, cardiology, blood-circulation

I've seen a claim that bigger persons generally resist g-forces worse than smaller in an undergraduate biology book. However this claim was supported by the argument that blood has to travel a longer way form the head to the heart.

However, I think this is not the only factor that matters. They generally should have a larger heart, but may need to pump more blood, so perhaps this cancels.

Questions:

- Has it ever been tested whether bigger persons generally resist g-forces better? If so, what were the results?
- If we only take scale factors in considerations, i.e. we take identical persons, but the one is 1.2 times as large as the other in all dimensions, what conclusion will we reach? What factors should we take into consideration?

Comment: You also need to include factors like Muscle/Fat ratios. Like you wouldn't wanna test a small athletic person against an overweight giant,

Comment: Has ever what been tested? And which scale factors?

Comment: @AliceD I have tried to clarify the question.

Comment: There are some good points on high G-forces in this discussion of launch-abort systems [http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8155/how-hard-is-it-on-the-crew-to-go-through-the-14-gs-of-a-launchpad-abort-of-the]. It is safe to say that within the size range of adult humans, the size of the person is not a _very_ important concern compared to which way (s)he is facing.

In general, though, larger-scaled things fail under lesser forces than smaller-scaled things because strength increases as a square function of linear measurements, whereas masses increase as a cubic function.

Comment: What is "g-forces"?? Can you please use standard terminology?

Comment: @WYSIWYG [G-forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force). Feel free to edit the question to add in a more biological correct term.

Comment: @wythagoras I don't think the term "g-force" is used in any scientific literature. I am not sure if I am getting too old for this but I have always seen and used "Gravitational force" or "acceleration due to gravity" in such contexts.